# How do you check that each entry in a dictionary is not empty in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

When trying to iterate over a dictionary, I tried to make sure that each value in the dictionary is not None or empty and an error is thrown. The code is bellow.

```
articleSummaries = {}
for techUrlDictionary in [newYorkTimesTechArticles, washingtonPostTechArticles]:
    for articleUrl in techUrlDictionary:
        if techUrlDictionary[articleUrl][0] is not None:
            if len(techUrlDictionary[articleUrl][0]) > 0:
                fs = FrequencySummarizer()
                summary = fs.extractFeatures(techUrlDictionary[articleUrl],25)
                articleSummaries[articleUrl] = {'feature-vector': summary,
                                               'label': 'Tech'}
```

And the error message looks like this.

```
----> 5         if techUrlDictionary[articleUrl][0] is not None:
      6             if len(techUrlDictionary[articleUrl][0]) > 0:
      7                 fs = FrequencySummarizer()

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

What would be the best way to execute these checks? So this error is avoided?

Comment: The error says that you are using a dict as a key in `techUrlDictionary[articleUrl][0]`, which means that `articleUrl` is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that each `dict` in the list has a key `0`. Since you are iterating through the list with the `dict`s, you can access the `dict`s as is:

```
articleSummaries = {}
for techUrlDictionary in [newYorkTimesTechArticles, washingtonPostTechArticles]:
    for articleUrl in techUrlDictionary:
        if articleUrl[0] is not None:
            if len(articleUrl[0]) > 0:
                fs = FrequencySummarizer()
                summary = fs.extractFeatures(articleUrl,25)
                articleUrl = {'feature-vector': summary,
                              'label': 'Tech'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code, and the wording of your question is a little ambiguous. As @Zvone said, you're using the url as a dictionary.

However, are you trying to do something similar like this?

```
articleSummaries = {}
for techUrlDictionary in [newYorkTimesTechArticles, washingtonPostTechArticles]:
    for articleUrl in techUrlDictionary:
        if techUrlDictionary[articleUrl][0]:
            if len(techUrlDictionary[articleUrl][0]) > 0:
                fs = FrequencySummarizer()
                summary = fs.extractFeatures(techUrlDictionary[articleUrl],25)
                articleSummaries[articleUrl] = {'feature-vector': summary,
                                               'label': 'Tech'}
        else:
            print("Empty entry")
```